# Yii CDbCriteria compare 2 attributes to a single value

Tags: php, sql, database, yii

Hi I am new to yii and I am currently working on a project and I am having trouble with CDbCriteria.

My target query is:

```
title LIKE '$_GET['search']%' OR description LIKE '$_GET['search']%'
```

Is it possible to attain same result like this using CDbCriteria compare?

Controller action :

```
public function actionClassifieds(){
    $model = new Classifieds('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    if(isset($_GET['category'])){
        if( $_GET['category'] == 0 ){
            $model->classified_category_id = '';
        }else{
            $model->classified_category_id = $_GET['category'];
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        $model->title = $_GET['search'];
        $model->description = $_GET['search'];
    }
    $this->render('classifieds',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

My model:

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('classified_category_id',$this->classified_category_id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
    $criteria->compare('price',$this->price,true);
    $criteria->compare('timestamp',$this->timestamp);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $criteria->condition = "title LIKE :t OR description LIKE :d";
> $criteria->params = array(
>               ':t' => trim( Yii::app()->request->getParam('search') ).'%', 
>               ':d' => trim( Yii::app()->request->getParam('search') ).'%');
> ```

Better using `Yii::app()->request->getParam($var_name)`

**UPDATED**

```
$criteria->compare('classified_category_id',$this->classified_category_id);
$criteria->compare('price',$this->price,true);
$criteria->compare('timestamp',$this->timestamp);

$criteria->addCondition("title LIKE :t OR description LIKE :d");
$criteria->params[':t'] = $this->title;
$criteria->params[':d'] = $this->description;
```